# Why does the train set not transform from words to Word2Vec Numpy vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, word2vec

While searching online, I was working on creating a Keras model for analysing tweets. However, in my efforts to utilize a LSTM for a sentence level sentiment analysis, I've encountered trouble.

My goal is to use the input matrix which is a numpy array of word token arrays  to index into the vocabulary dictionary to give me the numpy vectors and replace the words with the corresponding word  vectors.

There are numerous tweets which I wish to replace accordingly. Following is the code segment for a CSV file and a pre-prepared Word2Vec vocab with a million tweets extracted and previous model run succesfully.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(data.head(n).tokens),np.array(data.head(n).Sentiment), test_size=0.2)

tweet_w2v = Word2Vec.load("vocaber.txt")
vocabul = tweet_w2v.wv.vocab
x_train=np.asarray(x_train)

vectorz=copy(x_train)
for k, v in vocabul.items():
        vectorz[x_train==k] = v
print(vectorz[1])
```

The output appears unchanged when printed.

> [02:05<00:00, 7942.71it/s] [u'it', u'happens', u'.', u"it's", u'just',
>   u'his', u'phone', u'got', u'cut', u'off', u'so', u'ya']

Edit:

The data element stores one million such rows with the sentiment text tokenized.

Sentiment   ItemID  Date    NO_QUERY    SentimentSource SentimentText
0   1467810672  Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009    NO_QUERY    scotthamilton   is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result  School today also. Blah!
0   1467810917  Mon Apr 06 22:19:53 PDT 2009    NO_QUERY    mattycus    @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50%  The rest go out of bounds

Comment: For clarity, you should show what your `data` starts as – either in full or with a few example rows.

Comment: Thank you, added the rows of the input data CSV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you'll likely want to perform the same word-to-vector replacement on your test set, it'd be better to do it before the train/test split, on `data' itself.

And when you do it, rather than iterating over the vocabulary dictionary, you'll want to iterate over each example in your data, then replace each token within those examples according to a lookup on the Word2Vec model – *not* just its `vocab` dictionary, which doesn't have vectors as its values.

That is, something more like a Python list-comprehension:

```
data_vectors = [[tweet_w2v.wv(token) for token in each_example]
                for each_example in data.head(n).tokens]
# ...*then* do your split...
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(data_vectors),np.array(data.head(n).Sentiment), test_size=0.2)
```

Note that depending on the different number of tokens in each example, `data_vectors` here will also have a different number of vectors for example after the transformation. For typical later machine-learning steps, you'll likely need another step that converts all examples to same-sized vectors - perhaps by averaging all the token-vectors of each example together. But you haven't yet asked about that.

Comment: Yes, averaging the token-vectors is one way but I've got 30% loss with 85% accuracy  in sentiment analysis with this in a convolutional neural network setup. Also, when I try to predict with obviously polar sentiments, it gives me wrong predictions. I figure this is because I'm not modelling sequential relationships between the words, so this is why I'm trying to get word vectors inputted separately to  a LSTM.

Comment: This worked for me.

data_vectors=np.zeros((20000,15,200),dtype=np.float32)
def dict_get(key):
        try:
                item = tweet_w2v[key]
                return item
        except KeyError:
                pass

data_vectors = [[dict_get(token) for token in each_example] for each_example in data.head(n).tokens]